# scale_fill_gradient() function is not filling with correct colors

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2, colors

I'm trying to build a map with `scale_fill_gradient2()` function. But low and high color seems incorrect.

I uploaded my data: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fabricandofitfaber/R_Notes/main/myData/states_map.csv

My code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(maps)
library(ggmap)  

state_map <- map_data("state")

state_map <- state_map %>% 
  left_join(states, by = "region")

state_map %>% 
  ggplot(aes(long, lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = water_land)) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "#BC9354", high = "#243292", mid = 10.8) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

And the result plot is that:

[image]

As you see in the plot, low and high colors are not consistent with my selection in the `scale_fill_gradient2()` function. The color in the `low =` category that I chose is a [yellowish](https://www.colorhexa.com/bc9354.png) land color.  It is not reddish as seen in the chart. How can i fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mid` should be `midpoint`:

```
read_csv("~/Downloads/states_map.csv") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(long, lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = water_land)) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "#BC9354", high = "#243292", midpoint = 10.8) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks, I thought the cause of the problem was very different.